# Issue with route groups

Tags: php, laravel

The following is a portion of my routing file. However, whenever I visit the `/recipe` or `/recipe/{id}` url's i get the error

> Cannot redeclare class Recipe.

Recipe is the name of my model btw.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::any('/logout', 'LoginController@actionLogout');
    Route::get('/recipe/add', 'RecipeController@showAdd');
    Route::post('/recipe/add', 'RecipeController@actionAdd');
});
Route::any('/', 'HomeController@actionHome');
Route::get('/recipe', 'RecipeController@showIndex');
Route::get('/recipe/{id}', 'RecipeController@showItem');
```

---

If I alter the routing file to below the error no longer occur's. However, the url's are then obviously affected by the 'before'=>'auth' meaning it can only be accessed by those which are logged in.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::any('/logout', 'LoginController@actionLogout');
    Route::get('/recipe/add', 'RecipeController@showAdd');
    Route::post('/recipe/add', 'RecipeController@actionAdd');
    Route::any('/', 'HomeController@actionHome');
    Route::get('/recipe', 'RecipeController@showIndex');
    Route::get('/recipe/{id}', 'RecipeController@showItem');
});
```

Am I using groups wrong, or am I missing something.

**Edit:**
The controller file is as follows:

```
<?

class RecipeController extends BaseController
{

    protected $layout = 'layouts.home';

    public function showIndex()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('recipe.index')->with('recipes', Recipe::paginate(15));
    }

    public function showAdd()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('recipe.add');
    }

    public function actionAdd()
    {
        $recipe = new Recipe;
        $recipe->creator = Auth::user()->id;
        $recipe->title = Input::get('name');
        $recipe->serves = Input::get('serves');
        if (Input::hasFile('image')){
            $fileName = date('m_d_Y_h_i_s_a', time()).'__'.str_replace(' ', '', Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName());
            Input::file('image')->move('uploads', $fileName);
            $recipe->image = $fileName;
        }
        $recipe->save();
        Log::info(Input::get('method'));
        foreach (Input::get('method') as $index => $item){
            $method = new MethodItem();
            $method->content = $item;
            $method->order = $index;
            $recipe->Method()->save($method);
        }
        return Redirect::to('/recipe')->with('message','Wrong Username or Password');
    }

    public function showItem($id)
    {
        $recipe = Recipe::findOrFail($id);
        $this->layout->content = View::make('recipe.item')->with('recipe', $recipe);
    }

}
```

And the model:

```
<?php

class Recipe extends Eloquent{

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'recipes';

    public function Creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'creator');
    }
    public function Method(){
        return $this->hasmany('MethodItem', 'recipe')->orderBy('order');
    }   

}
```

**Edit 2**

It appears to be a problem with how Laravel's (or composers) autoloader is working. It appears that at the controller run-time the recipe model has not been instantiated, as detected with `class_exists('Recipe', false)`. However, when i run `class_exists('Recipe', true)` the error occurs.

**Edit3**

So the sort or answer I have found is to rename the recipe class (and file name, plus all references to it). I then had to create a blank file named recipe.php. This feels incredibly hacky, but it works so im going to stick with it for now. I wonder if maybe the controllers need to have completely separate name's from the Eloquent models?

Comment: Can you paste some more of the error? File, affected lines?

Comment: The full error is:
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Cannot redeclare class Recipe

Comment: It doesnt say which file is causing the error? It's weird cause the Recipe class should'nt be declared anywhere in the code you pasted.

Comment: The model file (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_test\app\models\Recipe.php). The code highligher thing is highlighting the last line of the recipe class (last line of the file)

Comment: Can you post the model, maybe the RecipeController too..

Comment: @Stromgren: Appended to the question

Comment: It's weird. You're sure that you have no other classes named Recipe?
Cannot redeclare class should only appear if two files is loaded containing 'class Recipe {..}'. Remember that all files in /models, /controller etc is autoloaded.

Comment: Just done a find in folder search and there is definitely only one recipe class. (The only other one to come up was the RecipeController which should register as a completely seperate name)

Comment: Change your Recipe class name (to Recipe2 ie) and see if it now complains of not founding one, not finding the other one doesn't means you haven't one and PHP is being very clear about that.

Comment: If I rename the file name it complains it can't find the file. This also happens if I change the class name and the class being called in the controller

Comment: Braders, this happened to me once when I did a `composer dump-autoload -o`, as soon as I undo it with `composer dump-autoload`, then the error was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to re-generate the autoload files. For me i just ran `composer dump-autoload -o`. It appears some users may need `composer dump-autoload`.

Many thanks to [user2094178](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094178/) for providing the solution.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple. You already declared a `Recipe` class. It has nothing to do with your routes file; so stop looking there. Do a search on your entire project with the query **"class Recipe"**.

Comment: Already tried that I am afraid. The only two classes returned are RecipeController and Recipe

Comment: Downvoting my answer isn't nice. If you searched your entire project you should have found the Recipe class in the concatenated files generated by -o option of composer dump-autoload.